# JMeter 5.0 search and expand all, select and delete nodes

Tags: notepad++, jmeter-5.0

I want to search a specific string in JMeter 5.0 test plan and then do a search and expand which is possible.
Now, I want to select all these nodes and delete them from the jmx file.
Is there any way to do so?
Is it possible to use notepad++ regular expression?

Comment: Mark the nodes and click delete

Comment: Please, [editi your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55158795/edit) and add Sample file and expected result.